# Ajax search popup from _Layout page in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have following Controller Action and view

```
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
       RepositoryClass sample= new RepositoryClass();
       ViewBag.listDetails = sample.GetDetails(null, null);
       return View();
    }
```

Dashboard View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ayout.cshtml";
}

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.listDetails)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.ID</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

So I want to add a popup search for this and search the result without refresh the page,

Further I added **popup search form** in **_Layout** page as following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")        
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Begin page -->
        <div id="wrapper">

            <div class="content-page">
               <div class="content">
                    <div class="container">
                        @RenderBody()
                    </div>
                </div> 
             </div>
       </div>


        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)              

            <form role="form" class="sss">
                <h3 class="panel-title text-dark text-center">Select Date Range</h3>
                <input type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate" class="inn">
                <input type="text" id="enddate" name="enddate" class="inn">
                <button id="btnSearch" type="button" class="ss">Search</button>                          
            </form>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
            alert("button clicked");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/SearchbyDates",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { startdate : document.getElementById('startdate').value, enddate: document.getElementById('enddate').value, },
                dataType: "json",
                Success: function (response)
                {
                    alert("Success");
                    $('table tbody').html(response);

                },
                error: function ()
                {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
            return false

        });
    });
</script>
```

Then I added following Controller action to fetch search result and show in same `Dashboard` view without refreshing the page

```
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
       RepositoryClass sample= new RepositoryClass();
       ViewBag.listDetails = sample.GetDetails(null, null);
       return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchbyDates(DateTime? startdate , DateTime? enddate)
    {
       RepositoryClass sample= new RepositoryClass();
       ViewBag.listDetails = sample.GetDetails(startdate, enddate);
       return Json(ViewBag.listDetails , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

But when I click `btnSearch` button I can see the alert which I put here, but its not directing to the `SearchbyDates` method when I debug this.

I can see only then Error alert only . whats wrong in my approach

Comment: remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` (your not strinifying your data)

Comment: @StephenMuecke now its directing to method but startdate enddate values are null

Comment: @StephenMuecke how can I strinifying my data here ?

Comment: Are the values valid dates for the server culture? What does `console.log($('#startdate').val());` return? (and you do not need to stringify the data - there is no point)

Comment: @StephenMuecke to view that I put like this `alert(console.log($('startdate').val()));` inside `$('#btnSearch').click(function () {` event then I can see "Undefined" popup

Comment: You missing the `#` in `$('#startdate')`

Comment: @StephenMuecke can't I get when I use `document.getElementById('`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125155/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 main errors with your code.

First you need to remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` from your ajax code. Or alternatively you could use `data: JSON.stringify({ startdate : ... }),` but there is no need to stringify the data

Second, your method is returning `json`, so in order to update the view, the code in the success callback would need to be

```
success: function (response) {
    $('tbody').empty(); // should give the tbody element an id and use that as the selector
    $.each(response, function(index, item) {
        var row = $('<tr></tr>'); // create table row
        row.append($('<td></td>').text(item.ID)); // add table cell
        ... // append td elements for any other properties of your model
        $('tbody').append(row);
    })
}
```

Alternatively, you can return a partial view of the table, in which case you need to change `dataType: "json"`, to `dataType: "html",`, and in the success callback

```
success: function (response)
{
    $('.container').html(response); // suggest you use id="container" rather than class="container"
}
```

and then change the controller method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchbyDates(DateTime? startdate , DateTime? enddate)
{
    RepositoryClass sample = new RepositoryClass();
    ViewBag.listDetails = sample.GetDetails(startdate, enddate);
    retirn PartialView("Dashboard");
}
```

I would however recommend you pass a model to you view, rather that using `ViewBag` in both your `Dashboard()` and `SearchbyDates()` methods

Comment: should I change `$('table tbody').html(response);` as `$('tbody').html(response);` if I'm going with second approach ?

Comment: Makes no difference, but I would recommend you use an `id` attribute and generate it as `<tbody id="xxx">` and use `$('#xxx').html(response)` (change `xxx` to what ever you want)

Comment: I just realize your _Dashboard.cshtml` view already renders a `<table> and `<tbody>` element, so you should you should be using `$('.container').html(response)` (see update)